# Cleanly Wrapping a Packet Object and Passing to Methods with Varying Parameters in Java

Tags: java, structure

Within a project I'm working on, I'm given an Object that represents one of many types of packets. What I need to do with this packet is wrap it so I can access its fields, and then pass it to a certain list of validators based on it's type.

I currently have it set up as a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Check>>`, where the String is the name of the packet type, and the ArrayLists are each filled with checks for a single packet type. The problem is when I need a different method to pass every different packet type to its checks, as there are going to end up being near a couple dozen of them.

Is there any way I can take a wrapped packet (that much I'm not having difficulty with), and pass it to a list of checks that will all run that specific type of packet, without different methods for each? I know it's possible with reflection but I'm not sure how the overhead will affect performance when there are roughly 20 packets per second per client and occasionally upwards of 500 clients.

```java
public void run(Object packet) {
    switch (packet.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
        case "Foo":
            check(new WrappedFoo(packet)); break;
        case "Bar":
            check(new WrappedBar(packet)); break;
        case "Baz":
            check(new WrappedBaz(packet)); break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    private void check(WrappedFoo packet) {
        checks.get("Foo").forEach(check -> { check.run(packet); });
    }
    
    private void check(WrappedBar packet) {
        checks.get("Bar").forEach(check -> { check.run(packet); });
    }
    
    private void check(WrappedBaz packet) {
        checks.get("Baz").forEach(check -> { check.run(packet); });
    }
    //and then repeating this several times more...
}
```

To put it simply, is there any way to improve ANY of the code above in performance or size? Without requiring anything at the start of every Check::run method or sacrificing *too much* performance? I've tried a few ways but they have all ended with invalid Java in one way or another.

Comment: What do the wrapper classes look like? Providing more details will help.

Comment: @iota They use reflection to get their parent class' fields and then just provide methods to get those. I'm doing it that way because I'm expecting to work with multiple versions of another program. I'm not sure what other details you might need about them.